# Difference Between Log-in with Facebook,Sign-in With Facebook,and Sign-Up With Facebook

Tags: users, experience

I have seen a lot of apps using sign in with Facebook, some apps using log in with Facebook and some apps using sign up with Facebook which the form is filled with Facebook data.

So what will be the pattern difference while using any of these?

Will be any collision between custom sign up and log in with Facebook users?

Or is it better if sign up is only based on custom sign up and then we ask users to connect social accounts? So in this case we generate only one user id.

Comment: sign in and log in have the same meaning!

Answer (score 2):

1. **Sign up :** Register to the service
2. **Log in/Sign in:** You've already registered. Both mean same that you enter somewhere where you are already registered

An interesting and detailed answer is available at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24384/what-is-the-difference-among-sign-up-sign-in-and-log-in

Answer (score 2):

When you're already been to a place "**Log in/Sign in**",

When you're first time, "**Sign up**"

Spotify's mistake:

[image]

> Finally they corrected.

Comment: OMG, spotify did that ! Thats silly mistake. Designer might had got fired. he he

Comment: <i>"Login with spotify details."</i> What? it is my details not yours.

Comment: @Nicolas What suprise me is the time to redesign. 3 years. oh no! source: http://androidux.com/work/before-after/